# Is $n$ square free if $\sigma(n)=2\varphi(n)$?

Tags: number-theory

I got stuck in the following.

Consider the number theoratic function $\sigma(n)$ as the sum of positive divisor of $n$ and $\varphi(n)$ as the Euler's totient function that counts the number of positive integers less than n and relatively prime to $n$.

We have to prove/disprove that if $n\in \mathbb N$ be a solution of $\sigma(n)=2\varphi(n)$ then $n$ must be a square free positive integer.

I think this should be true but I am unable to prove this.

What I approached so far is the following:

Say $n$ be not square free. In that case there is at least one prime $p$ such that $n=p^{a}m$ where $m, a\in \mathbb N, a>1, (p,m)=1$.

Then we must have 
$$\frac{p^{a+1}-1}{p-1}\sigma(m)=2p^{a-1}(p-1)\varphi(m)$$

No idea what to do next.

I considered the simplest case: $a=2$ then the above will reduces to 
$$\frac{p^{3}-1}{p-1}\sigma(m)=2p^{ }(p-1)\varphi(m)$$

Here RHS$\equiv 0[8]$. What about LHS? Can we show that it is not congruent to 0 mod 8 somehow, in order to establish the contradiction for the case $a=2$?

How to proceed ?

Comment: You should define $\sigma$ and $\phi$.

Comment: Edited just now.

Comment: "There is at least one prime $p$ such that $n=p^{2a}m$..." - this isn't true - $n=8=2^3$ is not squarefree, but no prime appears with even exponent.

Comment: what about now ? Any thing else is required to specify ? please let me know

Comment: For what it's worth, there are 11 such values of $n\le1,000,000$, and they are all squarefree.

Comment: Numbers $n$ such that $\sigma(n)=2\phi(n)$ are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A062699 and there are also some links and references there that might be worth a look.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was really a helpful comment indeed. It really gave me a great insight. Thank you once again @Gery Myerson

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$n=5^3\cdot17\cdot19\cdot79$,
$\phi(n)=5^2\cdot4\cdot16\cdot18\cdot78=2^83^35^213$,
$\sigma(n)=156\cdot18\cdot20\cdot80=2^93^35^213=2\phi(n)$.

Similarly for $n=5^3\cdot13\cdot29\cdot79$. I don't know whether these are the smallest examples.

Comment: Can you please share with me how did these two example come to your mind?

Comment: When I looked at the computer output for $n$ up to a million, I saw most $n$ were divisible by $5$. So then I programmed for all $n$ of the form $25m$, $m$ up to a million, and it found those two examples.